# Rails: problem with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a problem I can not resolve on a form

Here's my view:

> ```
> <h1>create manager </h1>
> <% form_tag :action => 'create_manager' do %>
>
>     <%= text_area :user, :nom %><br/>
>     <%= date_select :user, :date_embauche %>
>     <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
>
> <% end %>
> ```

and here is my controller:

```
  def create_manager
    tmp = params[:nom]
    p(tmp)
    render :partial => "adminpartial"
  end
```

The problème is that **params[:nom]** return alltime nil.

I think i'm not using correctly the **params** variable.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the params passed in your logs?

I guess you might find something in `params[:user][:nom]`as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area).

BTW, did you carefully read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)?